# The+superlative adjective+noun+prepositional phrase+ever

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases, grammaticality

Please consider the following:
1. He is the worst president of America *ever*.
2. They are still the best students in history *ever*. 
Is it right to put *ever* there or should we put it before the *of* phrases.

Comment: The idiom is `Superlative` + `Noun Phrase` + _ever_. The prepositional phrase is simply part of the Noun Phrase. _Ever_  after a superlative means 'of all' or 'in the world' -- an indication of a complete comparison.

Comment: So, you are saying that the two sentences are already grammatically correct, right?

Comment: Those sentences are, yes.

Comment: Okay. Thanks :)